# confusion excel install location in registry

Tags: c#

I am required to detect excel install location in registry and open  an excel file .I have found an example code .
    I have two problems Firstly there is no InstallRoot directorty in the given registry path in that code

> RegistryKey rootdir = excelKey.OpenSubKey(currentVersion +
>   @".0\Excel\InstallRoot");

But It does exist under this path (SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MicroSoft\Office)
     The Other problem I was getting the the message that says "can't Open in excel 
    because excel is not installed."So I thought that CurrentVersion returns worng value 
   in my case (since office 2007) It returns 120.0 instead 12.0

```
public void OpenInExcel(string filename)
        {
            string dir = "";
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey excelKey = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MicroSoft\Office");
            if (excelKey != null)
            {
                foreach (string valuename in excelKey.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    int version = 9;
                    double currentVersion=0;
                    if (Double.TryParse(valuename, out currentVersion) && currentVersion >= version)
                    {
                        RegistryKey rootdir = excelKey.OpenSubKey(currentVersion + @".0\Excel\InstallRoot");
                        if (rootdir != null)
                        {
                            dir = rootdir.GetValue(rootdir.GetValueNames()[0]).ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
            if (dir != "")
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

                startInfo.FileName = dir + @"Excel.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + fileName + "\"";
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    try
                    {
                        process.Start();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nCould not start Excel process.");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't Open in excel because excel is not installed.");
            }
        }
```

@Edit:I think  something goes wrong at this line that returns wrong value because It Works this way

> RegistryKey rootdir = excelKey.OpenSubKey(
>   @"12.0\Excel\InstallRoot");

I dont know why TryParse returns 120.0

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to set `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true`, `startInfo.FileName =  @"document.xls"` and let the OS do the rest?

Comment: You marked RenniePet answer. `This isn't intended to be an answer to your question`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't intended to be an answer to your question, but it might help you get the correct version number, and I can't post all this code in a comment.

```
  public const string CProgIdOutlook = "Outlook.Application";

  /// <summary>
  /// Method to get the Outlook version number, which will presumably be 11 (2003), 12 (2007), 
  /// 14 (2010) or 15 (2013). (I wonder what happened to version 13?) An exception is thrown if 
  /// this method is unable to provide an answer.
  /// 
  /// The technique used to get the version number of the "current" installed version of Outlook 
  /// is one of many possible methods that are described in various Internet sources, and is 
  /// hopefully the most likely to provide the correct answer with the least side-effects. 
  /// Problems with some of the alternative registry-based methods typically show up when 
  /// multiple versions of Outlook are installed or have been installed. The registry values can 
  /// also depend on x86 vs. x64 systems and whether Outlook was installed for one user or for 
  /// all users. Techniques involving querying the Outlook automation object have the 
  /// disadvantage of an instance of the Outlook program getting created - this can be seen in 
  /// Task Manager.
  /// 
  /// The idea for this code came from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240794
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>11 (2003), 12 (2007), 14 (2010) or 15 (2013)</returns>
  private static int GetOutlookVersion()
  {
     const string CRegistryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Classes\" + GroupwareProgIds.CProgIdOutlook;
     int outlookVersion;

     using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(CRegistryKey))
     {
        outlookVersion = GetOutlookVersion(registryKey);
        if (outlookVersion != -1)
           return outlookVersion;
     }

     using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(CRegistryKey))
     {
        outlookVersion = GetOutlookVersion(registryKey);
        if (outlookVersion != -1)
           return outlookVersion;
     }

     throw new MerliniaException(0x2d4a67fu, "No registry entry for " + CRegistryKey);
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Sub-method of above method to do the work for either HKLM or HKCU.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>11 (2003), 12 (2007), 14 (2010) or 15 (2013), or -1 for error</returns>
  private static int GetOutlookVersion(RegistryKey registryKey1)
  {
     const string CCurVer = "CurVer";

     if (registryKey1 == null)
        return -1;

     using (RegistryKey registryKey2 = registryKey1.OpenSubKey(CCurVer))
     {
        if (registryKey2 == null)
           throw new MerliniaException(0x2d43e5au, 
                                      "No registry entry for " + registryKey1 + "\\" + CCurVer);

        string currentOutlookAppName = registryKey2.GetValue(null) as string;
        if (currentOutlookAppName != null)
        {
           string[] sa = currentOutlookAppName.Split('.');
           if (sa.Length == 3)
           {
              int outlookVersion;
              if (int.TryParse(sa[2], NumberStyles.Integer, 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out outlookVersion))
                 return outlookVersion;
           }
        }

        throw new MerliniaException(0x2d4b29du, 
                               "Invalid registry content for " + registryKey1 + "\\" + CCurVer);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about ***double type*** and ***Culture***.

I try explain:

You get ***double*** `12.0` value.

And `ToString` convert to **12.0** in ***Culture en-US*** and convert to **120.0** in ***Culture es-ES*** (decimal separators not the same).

The problem was *parsing the version as a double*.

> Since the computer culture considers , as decimal separator and . as thousands separator

You can changes the code like this (when you tried `Double.TryParse`):

`if (Double.TryParse(valuename, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out currentVersion) && currentVersion >= version)`